# how to connect 4 random points with 4 no intersecting line segments?

Tags: geometry, line-intersection

The points are in a plane，marked with two numbers indicating coordinates.give out a connect sequence.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the convex hull. If it is a quadrilateral, you are done. If it is a triangle, you can break any of its edges apart to include the inner point.